# Is there a mathematical function that inverts a fraction if its less than 1?

Tags: fractions

Simple question really: has anyone standardized a function that reverses the operators when the result is less than 1, similar to how the absolute value works for addition?
That is:

$$f(2)=2  $$
$$f(0.5)=2  $$
$$f(0.2)=5  $$
$$f(1)=1  $$

Comment: Just $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ for $x<1$ and $x\mapsto x$ otherwise.

Comment: Yeah I know I was just wondering if that was ever defined like abs is, so I can just write that instead

Comment: Is your domain the set of positive real numbers?

Comment: $f(x) = \exp(|\log(x)|)$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: @MartinR Now that's cool, +1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking if:
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x, &|x|\geq1\\
\frac{1}{x}, &|x| < 1
\end{cases}$$
Has it's own special notation, like $\log$ or $\exp$? If so, no. But, if you're just asking for the above function, there it is.

Edit: forgot some necessary conditions on $f$. The function should be:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x, &|x|\geq1\\
b, &|x| < 1
\end{cases}$$
Where when $|x|<1$, $x=\frac{a}{b}$ with coprime $a,b$. Note that this function isn't defined for irrational $x$ when $-1 < x <1$.

Answer (score 4):

> ... similar to how abs works for additions?

Using the [group isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism#Logarithm_and_exponential) $\log: (\Bbb R^+, \cdot) \to (\Bbb R, +)$ and its inverse $\exp$ you can write that function as
$$
 f(x) = \exp(|\log(x)|)
$$
for $x > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

If its argument $x$ is assumed positive, use $\exp|\ln x|$. This can be extended to an even function on nonzero reals, viz. $\exp|\ln |x||$.